# Get the type of an element in Hpricot

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, screen-scraping, hpricot

I want to go through the children of an element and filter only the ones that are text or `span`, something like:

```
element.children.select {|child|
  child.class == String || child.element_type == 'span'
}
```

but I can't find a way to test which type a certain element is. How do I test that? I'd like to know that regardless if there's a better way of doing what I'm trying to do, but I also appreciate suggestions on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
element.name
#=> "span"
```